# Looking for an SQL statement which groups by type

Tags: sql, mysql

first, I was pretty lost giving this question a correct title.

I'm working on a system which allows me to find specific networking devices. A network device (called "system" in my example) has a number of ports, where each port can have a specific configuration. An example would be: Return all devices which have at least 2 ports of type 100BASE-TX and at least 1 port of 1000BASE-TX.

Here's my example table which is named "ports":

```
system  port  type
1       1     10BASE-T
1       1     100BASE-TX
1       1     1000BASE-TX
1       2     10BASE-T
1       2     100BASE-TX
1       2     1000BASE-TX
1       3     10BASE-T
1       3     100BASE-TX
1       3     1000BASE-TX
2       1     100BASE-TX
2       2     100BASE-TX
2       3     100BASE-TX
```

Column descriptions:
"system" is the ID of the system which contains the ports
"port" is the ID of the port
"type" is the type which that single port can have

I'm pretty lost here, and I don't ask for a complete query, maybe some hints are enough for me to figure out the rest. I already tried to join the table with itself to retrieve all possible port combinations, but from that point I was lost again.

Here's my pseudo-code:

> SELECT system FROM ports WHERE (number-of-possible-100base-tx-ports >= 2 AND number-of-possible-1000base-tx-ports >= 1)

Here's my expected result:

```
system
1
```

It is important to know that a port can be either of one or another type. Basically I want the user to ask: "List all devices which support 2 100BASE-TX ports and at least 1 1000BASE-TX port at the same time". For example, the following pseudo-sql should not return any results:

> SELECT system FROM ports WHERE (number-of-possible-100base-tx-ports >= 2 AND number-of-possible-1000base-tx-ports >= 2)

This query shouldn't return any result since no device has more than three ports overall.

**EDIT**

Here's another pseudo-SQL which represent the question better:

> SELECT system FROM ports WHERE (at-least-1-type = 1000BASE-TX AND at-least-2-other-types = 100BASE-TX) AND portid-from-type-1000BASE-TX <> portid-from-type-100BASE-TX

***EDIT #2***

After one night, I realized that it might not be possible using plain SQL. What I need would be an intermediate table containing all possible configurations per system, and I believe that table would be quite huge. Given the example table above, I would already have 27 different combinations for system 1; regular networking devices have 12, 24 or 48 ports and storing all combinations in a database wouldn't be very efficient. I have to think of a programmatic way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!
Timo

Comment: Can you please give an example output you need?

Comment: in your example date, is port an identifier or a count?

Comment: Ivan, I updated my question with an SQL pseudocode.
Dnagirl, port is an identifier.

Comment: I dont get it people post questions like this with sample data.  All you have to do is post the expected results (another set of data from the sample) how hard is it ?

Comment: I included sample data to give readers an impression of how the data is structured, I also included an pseudo-SQL query and I also included an expected result set.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I updated my question whenever I felt that the question wasn't understood.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a bash at this using SQLite and this query seems to work ok for the [limited test data I've tested it against](http://gist.github.com/231307).

```
select sys as system from (
  select a.sys, count(distinct a.port) as want_a, count(distinct b.port) as want_b
  from test a left join test b
  on a.sys=b.sys and a.port<>b.port and a.type<>b.type
  where
       a.type='$type_a'
   and (b.type='$type_b' or b.type is null)
   and a.sys in (
     select sys from test group by sys having count(distinct port) >= $want_a+$want_b
   )
  group by a.sys
  having want_a >= $want_a and want_b >= $want_b
) z;
```

Where $want_a is the count of ports for $type_a and $want_b is the count for $type_b.  So your initial query up there has want_a=2, type_a='100BASE-TX', want_b=1, type_b='1000BASE-TX'.

In [the gist](http://gist.github.com/231307), the first file is mysql.sh (test driver script, ./mysql.sh < test.txt), second is test.txt (test data), third is gotest.sh (sqlite3 driver script, ./gotest.sh < test.txt), third is the SQL.  All tests PASS in mysql and sqlite3 so that's promising.

Comment: Did anyone try my code and verify whether it answered the question or not? If it did, accepting the answer would be great...

Answer (score 0):

Well, first i might question this table structure... but from your description of the system you're working on it may be difficult to change...

I would suggest a query with two sub-queries like this:

```
SELCT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(port) AS Port1Count, system 
        FROM ports 
        WHERE type = '100BASE-TX' 
            AND Port1Count >= 2 
        GROUP BY system
    ) AS A 
INNER JOIN 
   (
        SELECT COUNT(port) AS Port2Count, system 
        FROM ports 
        WHERE type = '1000BASE-TX' 
            AND Port2Count >= 1 
        GROUP BY system
    ) AS B ON A.System = B.System
```

This may not be EXACT depending on the flavor of SQL and I may have some syntax wrong here or there since I didn't actually try building your table.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I formatted your code. I think it's more readable now. Avoid putting long queries in one line.

Comment: Unfortunately, your query has the same "problem" as the other queries - it returns the sum of all ports, no matter if a port is taken by another type already.

Comment: Sorry Timo, I guess I just don't fully understand the problem space here. Please respond to each assumption below with Yes/No to help clarify the problem:

1. There are systems
2. A system has many(<=3) ports
3. Each port has one port type
4. There are many ports of the same type on different systems
5. What is represented in the table is how the ports on the systems are currently configured
6. The port types can be reconfigured at a later time
7. You want to query to find systems that could be configured in a certain way in the future
8. You want to query based on the current configuration

Comment: 1.) Yes 2.) No, each device (system) can have any number of ports 3.) Each port have at least one type, but there's no limit of types a port can have 4.) Yes 5.) No, it just shows how each port can be configured on each device (system) 6.) Yes, but the table doesn't represent the actual configurations. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify this requirement a bit further:

> Return all devices which have at least
>   2 ports of type 100BASE-TX and at
>   least 1 port of 1000BASE-TX.

Since a single port can have more than one type, would this device satisfy the query or not?

```
port    type
1       100BASE-TX
1       1000BASE-TX
2       100BASE-TX
```

Taking your requirement literally, I think this device qualifies, but I suspect what you really want is a device which can support 2 100BASE-TX and 1 1000BASE-TX connections at the same time, so would need to have at least 3 ports.

Comment: No, it would not. You are right, the device would be required to have 3 ports, where 2 of them can be configured as 100BASE-TX and one of them as 1000BASE-TX.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to normalize the data.

```
Table 1:
System ID - key
Description

Table 2:
Port Type ID - key
Description

Table 3:
System ID - Key
Port ID - Key
Port Type

Select count(*), port_type from table_1 a, table_3 c
where a.system_id=c.system_id
group by port_type
having count(*) > 2
```

I hope that gets you close.

Comment: I agree, normalizing the database would be optimal, something just doesn't seem right about the way that table repeats I would hesitate to recommend a normalized structure without knowing more about the problem space though.

Comment: This table is actually part of a normalized structure which is similar to yours. What you see in my example corresponds to Table 3. The example query you posted doesn't correspond to my question; it simply returns the overall number of ports, but doesn't consider that a port with a specific id can either be of type 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX or 1000BASE-TX.

Answer (score 0):

After one night, I realized that it might not be possible using plain SQL. What I need would be an intermediate table containing all possible configurations per system, and I believe that table would be quite huge. Given the example table above, I would already have 27 different combinations for system 1; regular networking devices have 12, 24 or 48 ports and storing all combinations in a database wouldn't be very efficient. I have to think of a programmatic way to solve this problem.